# Redirecting a .sql file to .db file in Windows

Tags: sql, windows, sqlite, powershell

I have been trying to learn SQL by doing the exercises on the Learn SQL the Hard Way site.  I have made a file in folder on my desktop called ex1.sql, and I have put all of the sqlite3 stuff in PATH.  However, I am using Windows Powershell and I cannot perform the command:

```
sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
```

I am getting this error in the Powershell terminal:

```
At line:1 char:16
+ sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
+                ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupport
```

So, I guess '<' can only be used to redirect on Unix OS.  I have tried to find an equivalent command in powershell, but I have not found one yet.  If anyone has had this problem or knows how to redirect .sql files to .db, then that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
get-content ext1.sql | sqllite3 ext1.db
```

The article has a nice discussion of legacy redirection issues in Powershell and various workarounds:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/16/working-around-legacy-redirection-issues-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thank you!  I was unable to get it to work using the get-content method, but it did work when I used the old DOS command as explained in the article: _CMD /c "sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql"_

Comment: It is `sqlite3` not `sqllite3`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue following along with [Zed Shaw's Learn SQL the Hard Way](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/) on Powershell. The command he uses on **Unix** is

```
sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
```

Chad's answer works perfectly for Powershell. Zed is using the ['<' redirection](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/commandline/pipes.html#redir-input) to read the CREATE statement from the .sql file and use that is input to the .db file.

In this **Powershell** example, Chad is reading the content of the .sql file and ["piping"](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_pipeline.htm) it into the .db file.

you can also type

```
gc ex1.sql | sqlite3 ex1.db
```

I hope this helps anybody that stumbles across this post while following along with Zed, like me! Thanks Zed and Chad!