# How to execute SQLite script with UTF8?

Tags: powershell, utf-8, sqlite

I'm trying to `.read` a SQLite script that contains some German characters (umlaute *äöü* and *ß*):

```
sqlite>
.open test.db
.read test.sql
```

I've saved the sql file as utf8 without BOM because sqlite3 wouldn't read it with BOM and complains about an error in line 1 bug still, sqlite3 doesn't seem to read it as utf8 because when I  select a row with a `ü` all I get are question marks `?`. If I however add a `ü` in the console and select the same row the correct character is showed.

I also tried it with powershell:

```
Get-Content test.sql -encoding utf8 | .\sqlite3.exe test.db
```

but the result was the same (question marks).

What do I have to do to execute a ut8 sql script?

(I deleted the database for each test)

Comment: If the file is without BOM and Sqlite won't read a file *with* BOM, what is the problem here? Can you clarify what that part of the question means?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've rewritten the sentence: _I've saved the sql file as utf8 without BOM because sqlite3 wouldn't read it with BOM and complains about an error in line 1._

Comment: The problem is that it reads garbage like the file wasn't encoded with utf8.

Comment: I was able to import the file when I change the console's code page as suggested in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269224/how-to-print-sqlite-to-file-in-utf-8#comment30867086_20274260 I tried to change it for powershell too but it didn't work there :(

Comment: This solution finally worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/21759264/235671 this was quite tricky

Comment: Please note that with most versions of `sqlite3.exe`, UTF-8 I/O in the console does not work correctly. To check whether the DB contains correct UTF-8 data, better open it in any GUI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, to import via powershell a utf8 encoded file that contains national characters like the German *äöüß* is with this command [Running a Sqlite3 Script from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759264/235671):

```
.\sqlite3 test.db ".read test.sql"
```

the other popular solution [Redirecting a .sql file to .db file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077104/235671) does not work in this case and the result is question marks:

```
Get-Content test.sql -encoding utf8 | .\sqlite3.exe test.db
```

To view the results it's also important to change the encoding for the console with

```
chcp 65001
```

or otherwise you will see only garbage although the file has been correctly imported.

If you are working with C# you still won't see the correct string and you need to kind a re-encode it with:

```
value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value));
```